# How to correctly train with tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization: Is there still a tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS dependency?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, batch-normalization

My goal is how to correctly train with batch normalizations layers in TensorFlow (TensorFlow version 1.13.1 for Python in Graph Mode) using the recommended tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization class (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/BatchNormalization).

An older recommended approach was to use tf.layers.batch_normalization.  The documentation (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization) indicates that it is currently deprecating instead in favor of tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization.

While using the older class, the documentation indicates we must explicitly add dependency on the mean and variance update operations, which would otherwise be dangling nodes outside from any dependencies in training operations:

```
update_ops_including_from_batch_norms  =  tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
   my_optimizer = tf.super_cool_optimizer(loss)
```

My question:  Is this explicit dependence on UPDATE_OPS still needed when training batch norms in TF 1.13 with tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization?  I don't see this mentioned in the documentation, however, I would be much more comfortable if someone knew for sure (and even better if can point to official documentation or code) that these operation dependencies are implicitly taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, it's not needed. It is mentioned in the current documentation at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization.

On a side note, I'm currently using tf.layers.BatchNormalization WITH explicit dependence on UPDATE_OPS (TF version 1.10) because tf.layers.keras.BatchNormalization seems bugged to me. My model validation was failing while using tf.layers.keras.BatchNormalization. Maybe it has been fixed in the recent update.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the official doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.14/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization)

> In particular, tf.control_dependencies(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS) should not be used (consult the tf.keras.layers.batch_normalization documentation).

You should collect the update ops from `tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()` as follows. See [discussion](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16102#issuecomment-394527301)

```
...
batch_normalizer = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
normalized_tensor = batch_normalizer(raw_tensor, training=is_training)
total_loss = ... # Get loss tensor
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
minimization_op = optimizer.minimize(total_loss, global_step=tf.get_global_step())
# Get "regular update ops"
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
# Get BatchNorm updates
update_ops.extend(batch_normalizer.updates)
# Group two sets of operations to form a train_op
train_ops = tf.group([minimization_op, update_ops])
```